# Google Analytics model comparison tool shows all traffic as direct when it actually came from Facebook and Instagram

Tags: google-analytics, advertising, facebook

We have created a new site and we are doing an Ad Campaign in Facebook Ads. My problem is that when I go to Google Analytics to analyze my traffic with the Model Comparison Tool and I click to First Interaction Model all  my traffic comes from Direct traffic. I know that this is not real because all traffic comes from Facebook and Instagram in the first interaction.

Here is a screen shot. What can be happening?

[image]